# How to implement a simple responsive row/column structure similar to this bootstrap example with flex layout for angular4?

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I have been using angular 4 and the flex layout library( [Flex layout library](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki) ) I find the api confusing, and have checked several examples, and I just dont get how to implement a simple resizing row/column structure with this library. I would like to implement the following bootstrap code with the flex layout library. How would I create this bootstrap grid example with flex layout?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-4">
      Left column
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4">
      center column
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-4">
      Right column
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help as to how to do this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API

You should use the part in

> MediaQueries and Aliases

The result should be similar to this

```
<div fxFlex="20%"  fxFlex.md="40%">dummy div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**One thing to remember:** (helped me) unlike in Bootstrap, if you do not specify one of the media queries in Flex it will fall back to the biggest specified value. So if you don't specify **fxFlex.xs="25"** it will fall back to  **fxFlex.lg="33"** not fxFlex.sm="25".

```html
 <div fxFlex="100" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-around stretch">
    <div fxFlex.xs="25" fxFlex.sm="25" fxFlex.md="33" fxFlex.lg="33" fxFlex.xl="33">
        Left column
    </div>

    <div fxFlex.xs="50" fxFlex.sm="50" fxFlex.md="33" fxFlex.lg="33" fxFlex.xl="33">
        center column
    </div>
    
    <div fxFlex.xs="25" fxFlex.sm="25" fxFlex.md="33" fxFlex.lg="33" fxFlex.xl="33">
        Right column
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hope this helps someone! ;)